# remove association many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got the following mappings between two objects - events and customers:

```
//In the customer object
private List<Events> events = new ArrayList<Events>();
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="Customers_Events",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName="PK"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="EVENTS_ID", referencedColumnName="PK")
)
@OrderColumn
public List<Events> getEvents() {
    return events;
}

//in the Events object
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="events", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}
```

Then in my dao I have

```
@Override
public Customer getCustomerWithEvents(long aPk) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) getSession().get(Customer.class, aPk);
    Hibernate.initialize(customer.getEvents());
}

//The same method for events..
```

And in my controller I simply do:

```
Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerWithEvents(aPk);
Events event = eventsService.getEventWithCustomers(eventPk);
customer.getEvents().remove(event);
event.getCustomers().remove(customer);

customerService.saveOrUpdate(customer);
eventsService.saveOrUpdate(event);
```

So the code does not remove the relationship. When I do for example:

```
bool = false;
if(customer.getEvents().contains(event)) {
    bool = true;
}
```

It always returns false. It seems like I cannot delete the objects from the lists because hibernate cannot somehow match them? Any ideas on how to remove many-to-many association relationship?

Comment: Have you overriden `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `Customer` and `Events`?

Comment: do entities have a custom compareTo or equals methods inside?

Comment: Hi, 10x. No, I haven't. I never do it. Also, I see that you need to implement hashCode and equals only if you are going to use a Set and I don't use a Set? I use a list. Do you have any idea what's the recommended approach to implement it?

Comment: @george You may try to implement equals/hashCode based on the entities identifiers. See [here](https://github.com/sp00m/rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/boogiedev/rest/data/documents/support/GenericDocument.java) for an example.

Comment: @sp00m yes, I did it. And it works fine. The only concern I've got is that hibernate says that we must use a business key rather than the ID key but since I am using a list and not Set then I might have duplicates etc so I don't have any business key which may distinguish my objects except the ID identifier Hibernate generates. Do you have any suggestion on this?